# criminalise Moon landing deniers

Tags: criminal-law

Can people go to prison for denying a historical event?!

like people who deny moon landing, or people who deny jesus?

I am taking the example of denying holocaust in WWII.

it is a historical event that people wrote about and there are different stories about it.

similar to Moon landing, it is a historical event that people witnessed on TV and we have astronaut who died for that and other astronauts who did walk on moon.

why it is illigal to deny holocaust in many countries while it is ok to deny moon landing in these countries?!!!

Comment: "Why?" is [politics](https://politics.stackexchange.com/). Here we answer "what?"

Comment: The moon landing and the Holocaust have been proved. Jesus has not. Dont conflate the two.

Comment: @EkadhSingh Holocaust is a historical event, and as with many historical events, it might be exaggerated. while Moon landing was documented properly. So why the Holocaust questioning Holocaust is a crime in some countries why moon landing is not?

Comment: The Holocaust might be exaggerated, but it is true. Jesus cannot be proven true

Answer (score 6):

Countries define free speech protections differently, so it’s difficult to give a generalized answer. Nonetheless: the main razor used when limiting speech is harm. Most countries that have made denying the Holocaust illegal have done so out of a claim that such denial harms minority communities, as well as the national community.

Denying that the moon landing happened, however, is unlikely to harm anyone. While it is rather silly, it is not sufficient to take away somebody’s right to free speech.

Comment: if you mean emotional harm then yes denying moon landing is harming scientists and people who work in the space tech field. but if you mean physical harm. then I do not see any harm in questioning the number of people who died in the Holocaust especially when it is done in academic research

Answer (score 1):

Countries that criminalise things like denying the Holocaust do so because such arguments are used to bolster movements (in this case Neo Nazism) that then go on to harm innocent people (in this case the Jewish community). As such the law is there to protect the basic rights of a group of people.

Outlawing moon landing denial wouldn't have a protective effect, because it doesn't bolster a movement wishing to do harm to a group of people, so outlawing it would be unnecessary censorship.

Comment: There is a law for antisemtism to protect this minority! Holocaust is a historical event, denying it or doubting the number is valid and there are studies that its authors have been put in jail!!.. based on your answer why the same is not happenning for other minorities such as Bodist or Muslims or other religions?

Comment: @asmgx Because there hasn't been a large-scale attempt at an ethnic cleansing specifically to eradicate people of those ethnicities within living memory?

Answer (score 0):

In the US one cannot be punished for any statement that is historically inaccurate however it is crazy or wrong or disrespectful. The First Amendment provides that "**Congress shall make no law** respecting an establishment of religion, or prohibiting the free exercise thereof; or **abridging the freedom of speech**...". There are some limitations to that free speech clause, but publishing historically inaccurate statements is not one of them.

This is US Constitution and it was applied to states, too. See Gitlow v. New York, 268 U.S. 652 (1925) (dicta) and Stromberg v. California, 283 U.S. 359 (1931).